# Encoding issue when storing a cookie with quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I need to create a cookie containing double quotes.

```
cookies[:mycookie] = '"contentofmycookie"'
```

But then my cookie actually contains:

```
%22contentofmycookie%22
```

I've seen that Rails encodes cookie values; may be I should avoid this by overriding something but I don't know what. I'm using Rails 3.2.3.

**Edit:**
I need my cookie to contain double quotes to get it recognized by another application. This other application is not a Rails application and uses a cookie with quotes inside.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: a far as I understand it " is a special character and has to be escaped. Why do you care?

Comment: However there are cookies which contain double quotes. My question is: How to do this with Rails?

Comment: I still don't understand why you would need to do this, even if you need to retrieve the cookie in another language/application just unescape/decode it there instead. Internally rails delegates setting cookies to [`Rack::Utils::set_cookie_header!`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L220) which escapes the value, if you really want to change the functionality (and probably violate the cookie specification) I believe you would need to monkey patch it, but I *really* don't recommend doing this.

Comment: I got same problem while storing email id - @ is replaced by %40. any suggestion to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

You need to unescape your cookie when you extract it.

```
require  'cgi'
print CGI.unescape cookies[:mycookie]
#=> "contentofmycookie"
```

Comment: @plerrea Have you got Answer to this ?